# Will I be able to burn Win10 install media for a clean install?

Tags: windows-8.1, virtualbox, windows-installation, ubuntu-14.04

I received my Win10 upgrade notification. I am using a questionable (as in I torrented the software) Win8.1Pro license in VirtualBox on my Dell running Ubuntu 14.04. I'd like to be able to burn an install DVD or USB thumb drive of the Win10 OS to accomplish a clean install of Win10 on my Dell and then reinstall Ubuntu as a dual boot machine (ftw). Does anyone know if it is possible to burn media or make an install USB drive using VirtualBox? BTW my Dell came with a Win7 Pro sticker which is an OEM license but I am unable to find any media to reinstall Win7 and upgrade from there. Thoughts?